# The meaning of the following bash script

Tags: python, bash, base64

I have a quick question. I got the following bash script from my friend, but I don't know what `/inline/b64/` is, and how the following code segment works.

I have some experience with bash, and Python, but I cannot understand the following code fragment at all. Could anyone please give me some enlightenment?

More specifically,

1) What does `/inline/b64` mean? I did some search on the web, but I couldn't find any clues.

2)  What does the following command mean?

```
ENCODED_COMMAND=$(python <<EOF
```

3) What's the purpose of these kinds of encoding?

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND="FILTER file utterance_id /tmp/my_utt_list"

ENCODED_COMMAND=$(python <<EOF
import base64
print base64.urlsafe_b64encode('$COMMAND')
EOF
)

$BIN --edit_commands="/inline/b64/$ENCODED_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Answer (score 3):

1. This depends on what the value of `$BIN` is.  Presumably this is some other script which supports an `--edit_commands` flag.  You would need to what that other script is expecting for this value to be able to interpret it.
2. This is combining a couple of bits of bash syntax.  First, `$(...)` means "execute the enclosed command and capture its output as a string".  Second, the `<<EOF` means that the following lines until the second `EOF` should be passed to the standard input of the command.  So taken together, this is executing the Python script between the two `EOF`s, capturing its output, and assigning it to the `ENCODED_COMMAND` variable.
3. The script is taking some string, `$COMMAND`, and using the Python [`base64.urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode) function to encode it with [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  The encoded string is then being passed to some unknown command, `$BIN`, which will presumably do something with it — perhaps decode and execute it in some way.